# UDP out-of-order on the same route

Tags: routing

If I have UDP streaming connection between two machines in the internet (with fixed IPs). Will I receive packets out-of-order?

I know that out-of-order packets happens because some packets might be re-transmitted (as in TCP). So I think that since both ends have fixed IPs, so packets will flow on the same path (at least for enough long time).

Comment: Will you?  Impossible to determine.  **CAN** you?  Yes, absolutely.  Internet routers don't always route packets via the same path, and as a result certain packets my arrive out of order.  Typically, however, the route packets *from the same L4 connection* end up taking the same path.  But it isn't required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no guarantee that packets are received in order when using UDP, so yes, you can receive them out of order. Retransmission isn't available in UDP unlike you mentioned, this could be done on application level though.

Also, it may very well be possible that routers on the path between two endpoints loadbalance packets over various links, so you can't assume that they use the same path.

If you really care about packet ordering, UDP isn't the appropriate protocol.